# Find the derivative of $H(z)$.

Tags: complex-analysis

[image]

My try:

I got that $\lim_{\Delta z \rightarrow 0}\frac{H(z_0+\Delta z)-H(z_0)}{\Delta z}=\int_0^1 \frac{h(t)}{(t-z_0)^2}dt$. This RHS integral is defined on $\mathbb{C}-[0,1]$. Hence, $H(z)$ is analytic. But how could I find the derivative? Is it possible to evaluate the RHS integral without knowing what $h$ is?

Comment: You have already written down the derivative. You can't write it without an integral in the given situation.

Answer (score 1):

If your equality is true, then you're done. You showed the limit exists by finding its value. It happens to have an integral, but that's just notation. You have successfully solved this problem.